# bash for loop with range defined not working

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop

When I define range for a for loop, it doesn't seem to work.
If I define the numbers instead it does work.

This doesn't work:

```
range="10 {4..28..8}"
for i in $range; do
echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
10
{4..28..8}
```

This works:

```
for i in 10 {4..28..8}; do
echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
10
4
12
20
28
```

Comment: a couple kludges: `range="10 $(echo {4..28..8})"` or `range="10 $(seq 4 8 28)"`

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) say that brace expansion happens before parameter expansion. When you define `range="10 {4..28..8}"` no brace expansion happens because it is quoted. When you execute `for i in $range` it doesn't work like you intend because of the precedence.

Comment: Just to note, even without quotes, brace expansion doesn't occur on the RHS of an ordinary assignment. `range=10\ {4..28..8}` will still result in the literal string `10 {4..28..8}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array.

```
range=(10 {4..28..8})
for i in "${range[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

(The brace expression is expanded when the array is created, not when the for loop is executed. But it really doesn't make much difference.)